# Surprising behaviour of .ajax() promises in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Chaining two $.ajax() call as follows:

```
[EXAMPLE 1]
var promise1 = $.ajax({url: remoteUrl, type: 'POST'});
promise1.then(
    function() {
        $.ajax({url: remoteUrl});
    }
);
```

produces on the remote server, as expected, the following events:

```
ENTER api_ping() ...
.
.
.
leave api_ping() ...
ENTER api_ping() ...
.
.
.
leave api_ping() ...
```

However, using the following simpler syntax:

```
[EXAMPLE 2]
var promise1 = $.ajax({url: remoteUrl, type: 'POST'});
promise1.then(
    $.ajax({url: remoteUrl})
);
```

sequentiality is lost:

```
ENTER api_ping() ...
.
ENTER api_ping() ...
.
.
.
leave api_ping() ...
leave api_ping() ...
```

with my great surprise, as .then() is chainable and returns a new promise.

We might conclude that if .then() is not passed a function, but a promise instead,
then the new promise will have the same behaviour as the original one, which is a pity
as the second syntax is far superior when you need to chain a long list of calls
in sequence.

However, more weird things happen.
If you use GET instead of POST, as follows:

```
[EXAMPLE 3]
var promise1 = $.ajax({url: remoteUrl, type: 'GET'});
promise1.then(
    $.ajax({url: remoteUrl})
);
```

the original "correct" behaviour is restored:

```
ENTER api_ping() ...
.
.
.
leave api_ping() ...
ENTER api_ping() ...
.
.
.
leave api_ping() ...
```

I'm trying to figure out a reasonable explanation for this ... suggestions ?

Comment: you are executing the function right away in your 2nd example.

Comment: Still, this does not explain the 3rd example: same syntax, different behaviour

Comment: browser (or server) must be serializing GET request to same uri so it can reuse cache (if possible) or another browser/server behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are executing the function right away in your 2nd example.

In your 3rd example, browser (or server) must be serializing GET request to same uri so it can reuse cache (if possible) or another browser/server behavior.

if you want to keep things clear **i think** you can do:

```
var someUpdate1 = function() {
    return $.ajax({url: remoteUrl});
}
var someUpdate2 = function() {
    return $.ajax({url: remoteUrl});
}

var updates = someUpdate1
              .then(someUpdate2)
              .then(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of Javascript syntax and evaluation rules. In the second example, the `$.ajax({url: remoteUrl})` is called and its return value passed to the `promise1.then()`.

When `$.ajax()` returns it already has sent the request.

As for the timing of events on your server, it seems that the GET request is processed slightly faster **by your server** in this case, so that they are run sequentially on the server (the server finishes responding before it starts processing the next GET request knocking the door). This is by happenstance only; with enough retries you get them to run simultaneously as well.

As for the latter pattern, yes it could be possible to have a function like `$.ajax` that would return return a deferred function that would be called when the `then` is called, but why? The "pattern" you're using is really not a pattern at all, not many real program needs to trigger constant AJAX requests in a busy loop manner.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still confused, however. In the third example, the very same syntax is used; however, the second ajax call is executed only after the first promise has been resolved

Comment: For both GET and POST, the server sends back a response only after 10 seconds, 
to make sure no rush conditions occur. Thus I can safely infer the different 
behaviour OF THE CLIENT in the two cases by looking at timestamps in the web server access log:

with GET:

    [14/Feb/2015:09:14:16 +0100] "GET /api/ping/ HTTP/1.1" 200 108 
    [14/Feb/2015:09:14:26 +0100] "GET /api/ping/ HTTP/1.1" 200 108

with POST:

    [14/Feb/2015:09:15:38 +0100] "POST /api/ping/ HTTP/1.1" 200 108
    [14/Feb/2015:09:15:38 +0100] "GET /api/ping/ HTTP/1.1" 200 108

Comment: you have 2 POSTs happening there simultaneously

Comment: In the second example: 1 POST and 1 GET simultaneously; in the third example: 2 GET serialized